# Text animation using css to fade out and in a part of the text

Tags: javascript, css, animation, text

I'm trying to animate some text and I'm having some problems getting the result that I want. I have a poem (each sentence in its own div) that I wish to fade out, then fade in on hover, remain visible for a while, and then fade out again. Sort of like a game of finding the text and giving the user a hint on where to hover.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```css
.poem {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
cursor: pointer;
}

.hide {
opacity: 0;
transition: all ease 15s;
}

.hide:hover {
border: 1px solid black;
opacity: 1;
}

.hint {
-webkit-animation: fadeinout 30s linear forwards;
animation: fadeinout 5s linear forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeinout {
0%,100% { opacity: 0; }
50% { opacity: 1; }
}

@keyframes fadeinout {
0%,100% { opacity: 0; }
50% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cardo" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<title>Opacity 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="hint poem hide">I have emotions</div>
    <div class="poem hide">that are like newspapers that</div>
    <div class="poem hide">read themselves.</div>
    <div class="poem hide">I go for days at a time</div>
    <div class="poem hide">trapped in the want ads.</div>
    <div class="poem hide">I feel as if I am an ad</div>
    <div class="poem hide">for the sale of a haunted house:</div>
    <div class="poem hide">18 rooms</div>
    <div class="poem hide">$37,000</div>
    <div class="poem hide">I'm yours</div>
    <div class="poem">ghosts and all.</div>
    <div class="poem hide">Richard Brautigan</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So far I've only tried it with css but I would welcome any javascript suggestions too !

Any help would be extremely appreciated !

Thanks in advance !

Comment: can you post it on plunkr? and give me the url.

Comment: The result is on your explanation already. So, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @SalomonZhang only partially. The div that I have with the class hint won't display the other properties (poem and hide) once it finishes its initial transition

Answer (score 2):

Instead of forwards I just ran it one time so it didn't stop on the last frame.  Should work:

```
.hint {
 -webkit-animation: fadeinout 5s 1 linear ;
 animation: fadeinout 5s 1 linear ;
}
```

Working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/nsf25rz0/2/

Comment: Oh ! This is perfect ! Thank you so much !

Answer (score 2):

Please checkout this [`working example`](https://codepen.io/RaysOfTheSun/pen/VEKqpL)

```js
$(window).ready(()=>{
  // fade in the hint text
  $('.poem-hint').toggleClass('hide');
  // fade out the hint text after 3 seconds (3000ms)
  setTimeout(()=>{
     $('.poem-hint').toggleClass('hide');
  }, 3000);  
  
  $('.poem').hover((e)=>{
    $(e.target).toggleClass('hide');
  })
});
```

```css
.poem {
    transition: opacity 1500ms ease-in-out;
    opacity: 1;
}

.poem:hover {
  border: solid thin black;
}

.hide {
   opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container text-center p-4">
    <div class="poem poem-hint hide">I have emotions</div>
    <div class="poem hide">that are like newspapers that</div>
    <div class="poem hide">read themselves.</div>
    <div class="poem hide">I go for days at a time</div>
    <div class="poem hide">trapped in the want ads.</div>
    <div class="poem hide">I feel as if I am an ad</div>
    <div class="poem hide">for the sale of a haunted house:</div>
    <div class="poem hide">18 rooms</div>
    <div class="poem hide">$37,000</div>
    <div class="poem hide">I'm yours</div>
    <div class="poem">ghosts and all.</div>
    <div class="poem hide">Richard Brautigan</div>
</div>
```

If you want the text to stay visible for a longer time, just change `1500ms` to a number that satisfies your requirements :)

Comment: @AlonsoAg I've updated my answer. I didn't see that you wanted the first line to fade out after a few seconds :)